# Azure Functions: getting connection string from other file than local.settings.json

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have a azure functions .net core 2.2 project.
There is a class:

```
    public static class A
    {
        [FunctionName("abc")]
        public static async Task RunAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("topic1", "sub1", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string msg,
            [Inject] IInsertOrderAzureSqlFunction functionRunner)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

which uses ServiceBusTrigger. `Connection` for ServiceBusTrigger is obtained from `local.settings.json` file. 
Is it possible to put connection string in different file i.e. `secret.settings.json`? How to enforce ServiceBusTrigger to get Connection parameter value from other file than `local.settings.json`

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "connectionStringValue1",
    "SqlConnection": "connectionStringValue2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `ConfigurationBuilder` to add multiple `secrets.settings.json` or `prod.settings.json` etc and load it dynamically. Example code below.

Let's say you have a `secrets.settings.json` like this

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnectionString": "server=myddatabaseserver;user=tom;password=123;"
  },
  "MyCustomStringSetting": "Override Some Name",
  "MailSettings": {
    "PrivateKey": "xYasdf5678asjifSDFGhasn1234sDGFHg"
  }
}
```

#### Update 1

Make use of Dependency Injection using `IWebJobsStartup` and you can do it this way.

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        var myString = config["MyCustomStringSetting"];
         builder.Services.PostConfigure<ServiceBusAttribute(serviceBusOptions =>
            {
                serviceBusOptions.Connection = myString;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The trigger will only fall back to using the `options.ConnectionString`value if the connection string is not set by the attribute. So in your function definition, make sure to set `ConnectionStringSetting` to `""`:

Comment: Value assigned to ```Connection``` must be constant. Also the value represents setting name from ```local.settings.json```, so simply it will not work, if I try to assign connection string to ```Connection``` property.

Comment: @ael updated my answer, please try it out. It should work

Comment: I don't know if it was intended but there is ```ServiceBusAttribute``` instead of ```ServiceBusTriggerAttribute```? Here is the code line: ```PostConfigure<ServiceBusAttribute(serviceBusOptions```. I tried both ServiceBusTriggerAttribue and ServiceBusAttribute, it doesn't work. I receive a message:"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus' is missing or empty." I tried to set Connection="" and then I also tried to remove Connection parameter ```[ServiceBusTrigger("x", "x", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]```

Comment: Got it to work, however, I replaced the root configuration by adding the following line: "builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);". You also don't need PostConfigure.